# Facebook Messenger Delivery callback randomly missing

Tags: api, bots, facebook-messenger

My bot can send a response in multiple messages. I use the delivery callback to know that a message is delivered and the next can be sent. (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhook-reference#message_delivery)

It works great except that sometimes I didn't receive Facebook's callback. I see no exact schema, for the exact same conversation it can works perfectly or miss a callback.

Have you ever noticed this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opened a bug on Facebook plateform, answer is 'well do not rely on this delivery callback as it works mysteriously'

[Facebook ticket](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/656914711140729/)

**Update**

The day after I closed this bug, new callbacks have been available on Messenger Platform, and the echo callback works exactly as intended.

Documentation of Echo callback [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhook-reference/message-echo)

Comment: Boom, just the day after, facebook update its Messenger Plateform and the [Message Echo callback](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhook-reference/message-echo) works perfectly.

Comment: Oh wow I didn't even realize that was a thing. Wasn't subscribed to it for some reason so I thought deliveries were the right way to handle them. So now that echos serve the purpose we're looking for, is there any use for the deliveries?

Comment: I'd like to know if there's any. Maybe the next update will explain what this callback can be used to.